# Render simple form partial in Rails/Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to render my form partial in javascript erb file.  When I place it in there it gives me a no method error.  Any ideas?

script.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".enquiry-button").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if ($(this).parents('.cell').find('form').length == 0) {
        $(this).closest('.cell').append(
            "<div class='enquiry-form'>" +
            "<%= escape_javascript( render '/static/form' ) %>" +

            "</div>");


        $(this).closest('.cell').find(".enquiry-form:last").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.cell').find(".enquiry-form:last").slideToggle("fast");
    }

});
});
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_messages %>
            <%= f.input :email %>
            <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

error

```
NoMethodError in Static#home
Showing /Users/colton/kitchen_ninja/kitchen_ninja/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb     where line #6 raised:

undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007f90cc875c80>:0x007f90cd2017e0>
  (in /Users/colton/kitchen_ninja/kitchen_ninja/app/assets/javascripts/script.js.erb)
Extracted source (around line #6):
```

Comment: Please post the exact `error`.

Comment: Try giving like this `"<%= escape_javascript( render partial: '/static/form' ) %>"`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two separate things together. Your `render` needs to run on the server. JavaScript's job is just to make an AJAX request and get a resource.

So, supposed you were to to this:

```
$.ajax(url: "/test").done(function(html) {
    $("#results").append(html);
});
```

AJAX's only role is to grab a remote resource and parse the results.

In Ruby, you can use `render` to emit the HTML:

```
<%= escape_javascript( render '/static/form' ) %>
```

Just make sure you point the AJAX request to the right resource so Ruby can do the rest of the magic.

Comment: Hate asking this,  How would I structure the ajax.  Not much of javascript guy...

Comment: I recommend the [guides.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) You are asking the right questions. It just needs a server / client approach. Think of Rails as the HTML making machine. AJAX enhances this through partial updates.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are pre-processing the script with `.erb`, you could use Ruby's string interpolation to return the partial as a string literal in the JavaScript file.

```
html = "<div class='enquiry-form'>" +
         "#{j render partial: 'static/form'}}" +
       "</div>"
$(this).closest('.cell').append( html );
```